# How to trigger ngClick programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to trigger `ng-click` of an element at runtime like:

```
_ele.click();
```

OR

```
_ele.trigger('click', function());
```

How can this be done?

Comment: No, i want to know the mechanism through which i can trigger ng-click manually.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

The syntax is the following:

```
function clickOnUpload() {
  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#myselector').triggerHandler('click');
  });
};

// Using Angular Extend
angular.extend($scope, {
  clickOnUpload: clickOnUpload
});

// OR Using scope directly
$scope.clickOnUpload = clickOnUpload;
```

More info on Angular Extend way [here](http://moduscreate.com/angularjs-tricks-with-angular-extend/).

If you are using **old versions of angular**, you should use **trigger** instead of **triggerHandler**.

If you need to apply stop propagation you can use this method as follows:

```
<a id="myselector" ng-click="clickOnUpload(); $event.stopPropagation();">
  Something
</a>
```

Comment: what version of angular are you using. triggerHandler seems to work fine in 1.2.1: http://jsfiddle.net/t34z7/

Comment: please explain why $(elem).click() doesn't work with Angular?

Comment: If you are limited to jqLite and can't use a selector, do this instead: angular.element(document.querySelector('#mySelector')).trigger('click');

Comment: @DanielNalbach in current (and not so current) Angular versions 1.2+, you have to use `triggerHandler` instead of `trigger`

Comment: Yea `.trigger()` is not a function in jqLite

Comment: Why did they remove `trigger`? It seems better/easier than `triggerHandler`. For one thing, `triggerHandler` does not even call the default browser `click` event, only the handlers you already attached.

Comment: I'm not so sure this still works...angularjs 1.6 this seems to not be working with full jquery

Answer (score 84):

```
angular.element(domElement).triggerHandler('click');
```

**EDIT:**
It appears that you have to break out of the current $apply() cycle. One way to do this is using $timeout():

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element(domElement).triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t34z7/

Comment: even this is nor working, its throwing following error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)

Comment: Can you replace the body of your click handler function with this line: alert('boom')? Can you see the alert?

Comment: You are going to have to show us a test case. Please send a fiddle if you want further assistance.

Comment: are you sure triggerHandler will fire ng-click event?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3668/ here is a small fiddle. Click on third check box and FIRST check box should also get selected

Comment: You probably want to use Angular's `$timeout` rather than `setTimeout`, as `$timeout` will run an `$apply` cycle for you if necessary. It also makes your code more testable as ngMock gives you full control over when `$timeout`s are executed. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Actually this should be `$timeout(fn, 0, false);` so that it doesn't invoke $apply, shouldn't it?

Comment: $timeout will break out of the current $apply cycle even with delay=0. So in the context of this question, the third argument is irrelevant.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. triggerHandler works. trigger does not in v1.2.25

Comment: dont forget to add '$event.stopPropagation();' just after the function start

Comment: @WildlyInaccurate you sure $timeout is for angular and not jquery, cause when i call $timeout, it say "ReferenceError: $timeout is not defined" ...
`txtNickName: function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    angular.element('#btnStartChat').triggerHandler('click');
                    //angular.element('#btnStartChat').trigger('click');
                }, 0);`

Comment: @deadManN `$timeout` is a service and as such needs to be dependency-injected before you can use it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 20):

This following solution works for me :

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myselector')).click();
```

instead of :

```
angular.element('#myselector').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: @DotKu Maybe you are already in a $scope function like when you use in a $timeout function ? In other words, you can't call a $scope.$apply() in a $scope.$apply()... I hope this might helps you.

Comment: @jpmottin I found it, it must be placed in $timeout. Thanks

Comment: OMG, Angular totallt ruined it. Why can't they mimick jQuery's ``$('#element').click()``

Answer (score 13):

Just in case everybody see's it, I added additional duplicating answer with an important line which will not break event propagation

```
$scope.clickOnUpload = function ($event) {    
    $event.stopPropagation(); // <-- this is important

    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(domElement).trigger('click');
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This finally worked for me in 1.5.11, and full jquery dependency.               $timeout(function() {
                var el = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-chevron-up');
                angular.element(el).trigger('click');
            }, 0);

Answer (score 10):

Using plain old JavaScript worked for me:
`document.querySelector('#elementName').click();`

Comment: Yeah. Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is to use:

```
domElement.click()
```

Because the angularjs triggerHandler(`angular.element(domElement).triggerHandler('click')`) click events does not bubble up in the DOM hierarchy, but the one above does - just like a normal mouse click.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Answer (score 4):

You can do like

```
$timeout(function() {
   angular.element('#btn2').triggerHandler('click');
});
```

Comment: I get this error for this solution in my ng 1.5.3 app: Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work (throw an error when clicked):

```
$timeout(function() {
   angular.element('#btn2').triggerHandler('click');
});
```

You need to use the **querySelector** as follows:

```
$timeout(function() {
   angular.element(document.querySelector('#btn2')).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple sample:

**HTML**

```
<div id='player'>
    <div id="my-button" ng-click="someFuntion()">Someone</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#my-button').triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

What this does is look for the button's `id` and perform a click action. Voila.

Source: https://techiedan.com/angularjs-how-to-trigger-click/

Answer (score 0):

Include following line in your method there you want to trigger click event

```
angular.element('#btn_you_want_to_click_progmaticallt').triggerHandler('click');
});
```