# How to call java script function bound to angular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my angular view page, I  have an div id whose click event is written in other java script file . Like a common java script file which is not related to the angular application. How to trigger the click event. The function in common javascript file is never triggered .

```
<div id="click" ..../>
//below one never works
$("#click").click(){
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that, just use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive of angularjs.

```
<div id="click" ng-click="myFunc()" />
```

In your javascript file:

```
$scope.myFunc() = function () {
    // Do something
};
```

Comment: No but this is a common file and function that is for all the modules which are not angular implementation.

Comment: @user2375298 Check if this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically helps

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new module and controller with the file that contains the functions, then create a dependency for this new module/controller.

**Auxiliar.js**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('auxiliar',[]);

app.controller('CtrlAuxiliar',function(){

    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("Hello!");
        alert("Hello!");
    };


    });
})();
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test',['auxiliar']);
  ...
  ...
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="auxiliar.js"></script>
...
...
<div ng-controller="CtrlAuxiliar as ca" ng-click="ca.sayHello()">Say Hello</div>
...
```