# How to call ng-change when the ng-model is changed but not explictly

Tags: angularjs, binding

Well, the title of question might not be clear. So here I explain:

I have an input field I1 whose ng-model is binded to an object.

Then I have **few more input fields**, whose values if changed are summed together and reflected in ng-model of I1.

Now when, the I1 is changed explictly by typing in input box, its ng-change gets triggered. However, if the value of I1 changes due to change in **few more input fields**, the ng-change of I1 is not triggered.

In short, the value displayed in I1 is changed due to changes in **few more input fields**, but its ng-change is not triggered.

How do I trigger ng-change, even when ng-model is soft updated
I hope, readers get the idea here, as I know it has become bit complicated to read

Comment: Please share related code for better understanding.

Comment: the reading complication can be reduced if you share the code

Comment: if you wanna trigger an event when model value of field **I1** is changed you probably should use the `$watch` function.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this issue?

Comment: Well I guess, this was not an issue at all. It is the expected behavior of `ng-change`. It triggers only when user changes the model explicitly. The correct way to achieve will be using a $watch as suggested by Rabi, Chetan and Michael. I wonder how I missed to select one of them as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a watch on your model and achive your desired result -

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="l1" ng-change="doSomething()" />
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.l1;}, 
       function(newVal, oldVal) {
         if (newVal !== oldVal) {
             $scope.doSomething();
         }
});
```

Alternatively, you can look at this thread - [How to trigger ng-click [AngularJS] programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)

But the first approach is recommended.

Comment: Thanx Rabi and Chetan as both suggested same approach. However, how is it possible to use $emit in this case, I just realized that **few more input fields** are within the ng-repeat of the div where I1 is.**. Can I fire a `$emit('ng-change', arguments)` or something like this to propagate the change upwards

Comment: yes, you can. But if the operation is on same controller, you wouldn't want to emit an event, watch would suffice your need.

Answer (score 0):

Get the idea from below example:-

> function MyController($scope) {
>
> $scope.modelVar = 1;
>
> $scope.$watch('modelVar', function() {
>
> ```
>      alert('hey, modelVar has changed!');
>
>   // here you can call onChange event.
> ```
>
> });
>
> }