# Native javascript click on on dom element

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, click

I need to call a click operation in native javascript. I got the following element:

```
<svg class="pull-right svg-cross ng-isolate-scope" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-svg-icon="" icon="cross" ng-click="dismissBanner()">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-cross"></use>
</svg>
```

I seems to be a website that uses angular. I would like to click on the element such that the function `dismissBanner()` gets properly called. Therefore I tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right svg-cross ng-isolate-scope')[0].click();
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right svg-cross ng-isolate-scope')[0].onclick();
```

However, both attempts have failed. I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].onclick is not a function(…)`.

I also called the `dismissBanner();` function directly, however, then I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: dismissBanner is not defined(…)`

How should I do that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is the working approach:

```
angular.element('.svg-cross').trigger('click');
```

Source: [How to trigger ng-click [AngularJS] programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)

After chatting with the OP, we found that the version of Angular used is `1.3.17`. For this version, the correct approach to trigger a click is this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right svg-cross ng-isolate-scope')[0];
angular.element(el).triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the following error, when calling this: `Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/jqLite/nosel(…)`

Comment: @toom I just updated the answer to include only one class name, as well as changing `triggerHandler` to `trigger`. Could you try it one more time?

Comment: I tried your new suggestion. Unfortunately it causes an error.

Comment: I posted the error in the first comment. I tried it in Chrome. I even get an error by just calling `angular.element('.svg-cross')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93060/discussion-between-dmytro-shevchenko-and-toom).

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a click by dispatching an event to the element. There's an object for that ([Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)), but the constructor is not supported in IE. You can overcome that with a deprecated API ([document.createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)):

```js
function mock() {
  var evt;
  try {
    evt = new Event('click');
  }
  catch(e) {
    evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  }

  document.getElementById('trgt').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

```html
<div id="trgt" onclick="alert('clicked!')">Don't click me</div>
<div onclick="mock()">Click me!</div>
```