# Trigger Click , or Modal

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to access the Udemy site and trying to log in via javascript , but I am unfortunately not able to trigger the click action on "log in" link.
[This is the url](https://www.udemy.com/java-web-services/).
`.click()` does not seem to be working , when I select the element.
Basically only after I trigger the link with a "click", the modal opens up.
And since the `.click()` is not working on the link , I am not able to open the login modal.

```
    var id = document.getElementById("id_email");
    var password = document.getElementById("id_password");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit-id-submit");
    id.value = "XXXX@gmail.com";
    password.value="XXXXX";
    submit.click();
```

**The above script works for me**  **only if I manually click** the Login link and then execute this script.
    Like I said I want the click() action on the login button to work , so I can completely automate this login action.

I am struck on how to trigger the click on this element

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("require-auth")[0].querySelectorAll("a");
```

Although the element is selected. when I try the click() on the element , I get the following error

```
  VM2907:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0].querySelectorAll(...).click is not a function(…)
```

Comment: please post what you have tried (html/script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: update your question with html and script

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as I tried that method and this I believe happens to be a special case. Also as you can see , I am able to successfully trigger the form, but not the modal. And If the modal is not triggered first, the form elements are not in the DOM and hence not picked by the selectors. :(

Comment: @user2977259 its not a simple click event that gonna work for you, website's code is an *AngularJS* based code, so you need to follow something like this [**SOAnswer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24334176/4763084)

Comment: @user2977259 I copied code from attached answer, modified it to trigger `click` event, pasted into console and modal opened...

Comment: @pwolaq  Can you please post the answer. I am still having difficulty.

Comment: Thanks @vivekkupadhyay. It works , this works for me angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("require-auth")[0].querySelectorAll("a")).trigger('click'); P.S: trigger does not work for me not triggerHandler does. I think this depends on the AJS version.

Comment: @pwolaq Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try `submit.trigger("click")` / `$(submit).trigger("click")` **instead** of `submit.click()`;