# Click in dropdown menu of AngularJS by script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to click the dropdown menu of angularjs by script

In this page we have some dropdown menu.
I want to click in there.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

[Click in there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EuNF.png)

I tried, but it didn't work

element.click();

element.trigger("click");

angular.element(element).scope().openMenu();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger ng-click \[AngularJS\] programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)