# How to trigger ng-click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<a role="button" id="trigger" class="qui-button" ng-click="ctrl.openDialog(); ctrl.triggerClick();">Confirm Dialog</a>
```

I want to trigger this by pressing another button, i was using jquery to trigger the click event by:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("trigger").click()
}
```

I trigger the click event, but ng-click event did not work.

How could i fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger ng-click \[AngularJS\] programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)

Comment: Try change ctrl => $ctrl, as in ng-click="$ctrl.openDialog();...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just have the other button with an ng-click equal to the same function?

Comment: This is the right solution. It's pointless and confusing to force dom manipulation into your code in order to trigger a click on an element to run some behavior. It will confuse future devs, this is what ng-click is for