# Trigger the click event on an element if a condition is true in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an Angular js view.html page where I am passing a string called **datadict** from the  $scope method of the controller.
Value  {{ datadict.days }} is displaying value **Nearly everyday** and  {{ datadict.days.includes('Nearly everyday') }} is showing result **true**.

Here is my code :

```
 <div class="some_class">
  <ul class="ex1">
    <li><a ng-click ="datadict.days.includes('Not applicable')" class="mdcl-tab1">Not applicable</a> </li>
    <li><a ng-click ="datadict.days.includes('Several Days')" class="mdcl-tab1">Several Days</a> </li>
    <li><a ng-click ="datadict.days.includes('More than half the days')" class="mdcl-tab1">More than half the days</a> </li>
    <li><a ng-click ="datadict.days.includes('Nearly everyday')" class="mdcl-tab1">Nearly everyday</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And when an element gets clicked, the event is handled by this function :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".mdcl-tab1").on('click',function(){

        $(this).addClass('tick');
        $('.ex1').attr('id', 'ex1');

    });

});

</script>
```

The problem is I want to trigger the click event on that `<a>` element for which the above condition is true that's why I added this condition **ng-click ="datadict.days.includes('Nearly everyday')"** but I am not getting the desired result. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: but title of question is saying something else

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to trigger the "click" event when the condition becomes true? Or do you want to enable the "click" event in that case?

Comment: what do yo mean by trigger the click event on condition true? do you mean trigger as in element.click() or do you want execute some method when the condition is true?

Comment: does these anchor tags have a click handler bound else where? they are definitely not bound in angular, I suppose. Its really hard to solve the problem, when we dont understand the context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger ng-click \[AngularJS\] programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".mdcl-tab1").on('click',function(){

    $(this).addClass('tick');
    $('.ex1').attr('id', 'ex1');

});

if($scope.datadict.days.includes('Nearly everyday')){
$(".mdcl-tab1").trigger("click");
}
});
```

and remove the ng-click attribute from the anchor tag

```
<a class="mdcl-tab1">
```

Comment: Sorry,Not what I am looking for. $(".mdcl-tab1").trigger("click"); will trigger click for all <a> elements.I need that specific element for which the condition is true. Almost there,so the upvote.

Comment: You could either change the class name for each anchor tag to differentiate between them or you could add an id attribute to each anchor tag and use the id as the selector and trigger the click event for each of the anchor tags

Answer (score 2):

i think you can do something like this

```js
<li><a ng-click ="datadict.days == 'Nearly Everyday' && someFunction()" class="mdcl-tab1">Not applicable</a> </li>
```

then if you click that ,someFunction() will only run if datadict.days is equal to 'Nearly Everyday'

Comment: Zulian,I don't want to check the condition after I click on the element,I want to trigger click on this element if a condition is true.

Comment: Well you cant trigger the click.. But you can call a function like if(true) { someFunc() }